# Adding or subtracting elements within list of list component wise

Tags: python, pandas, list, zip, element

How do I add elements of lists within a list component wise?

```
p=[[1,2,3],[1,0,-1]]
```

I have tried the following:

```
list(map(sum,zip(p[0],p[1])))
```

Will get me `[2,2,2]` which is what I need. But how to extend it for a variable number of lists? For example, `p=[[1,2,3],[1,0,-1],[1,1,1]]` should yield `[3,3,3]`.

A solution I figured out is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
p=[[1,2,3],[1,0,-1],[1,1,1]]
list(pd.DataFrame(p).sum())
```

Is there a more "Pythonic" way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `*` for unpack lists:

```
a = list(map(sum,zip(*p)))
print (a)
[3, 3, 3]
```

In numpy solution is similar like in pandas:

```
a = np.array(p).sum(axis=0).tolist()
print(a)
[3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Very impressive solution!

Comment: Thank you. I knew this was the right idea I just didn't realize the unpacking operator could organize the zip object the way I needed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use * to unpack the list and sum to sum it up.
If you are uncomfortable with the map function you can do it like this:

```
p = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [-5,-7,-9]]

sum_list = [sum(elem) for elem in zip(*p)]

print(sum_list)
```